# How to rotate the android action view

Tags: rotation, actionview

I am making android program.
I tried to show pdf in web view.
So, I created a new action view (...) and loaded a pdf file in my view.
And I also have a description of "android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"" in the manifest XML.But, if i rotate the phone screen , the action view doesn't rotate.
Why is this phenomenon caused? 
I really don't know the correct reason.
I want to help me...